# Linking multiple assembly files

Tags: linux, assembly

I am attempting to link an assembly main file to external functions, but I keep getting the 'undefined reference to function X in main'.

I have a folder full of external files which all are correct names and are .s files.

I do know that others have this issue as well, but they seems mostly focused on C and assembly files but this is only linking assembly files.

This is my code when compiling:

```
gcc -o main.o main.s -I lib/ -no-pie
```

Error that occurs when trying to compile:

```
/tmp/ccMgNx1L.o: In function `main':
(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `funcA'
(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `funcB'
(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `funcC'
```

Some extra clarity:
The lib folder contains all the functions referenced in the main.s file.
I wish to compile all files into an executable.

Comment: if you want to compile a source file into an object file, pass the option `-c` to `gcc`.  Otherwise gcc is trying to link.  Otherwise, please post a [mcve].  I'm not quite sure what you think is supposed to happen.

Comment: I wish to compile the files into an executable object file.

Comment: There is no such thing as an executable object file.  Either you have an object file (not linked) or an executable file (linked).  Which of the two do you want?

Comment: An executable file:p

Comment: in general (there are some rare exceptions, gnu not being one) c is compiled to assembly language and then assembled to an object then linked into the final binary.  so with gcc/gnu what you do in C is no different than what you do in asm, from a tool perspective (well you can use the assembler not the c compiler to assemble a program).  what will differ is if your assembly language is not doing what you think it is doing relative to an equivalent C program.  Please provide a minimal example, in the mean time write a C program main.c that calls these functions and use..

Comment: the same command line in the same directory except main.s is main.c or something else....does it find the functions to link in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `gcc -no-pie -o main main.s lib/*.s`  to assemble all your source files and link them all into one executable.

---

Note the lack of `.o` on the output file, because you're assembling+linking to an executable, not just to an unlinked `.o` object file.

`-I` sets the include path for `#include <>` and `#include ""`.  It's totally irrelevant here.  So would `-L lib/` because you didn't tell gcc to link any libraries.  Only where to look for any libraries if you *did* link any.  (But you don't have `.a` or `.so` libraries, you have asm source files that aren't assembled yet.)

If you had `main.S` (capital S), gcc would run it through the C preprocessor first, so you could `#include "foo.s"` in main for all the functions you actually use.  And `-I` to set the include path would avoid needing `#include "lib/foo.s"`